# What is this regex doing?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I thought this regex was about turning words into an array, but I get null as a result

when I want to get the second word from "facebox otherword" with array[0]

This is the regex:

```
this.rel.match(/facebox\[?\.(\w+)\]?/)
```

Thanks Richard

Comment: Is your question about what the regex does or how to get the second word from "facebox otherword"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex matches:

facebox.abc
facebox[.abc
facebox[.abc]
facebox.abc]

with `abc` being at least one "word character" (letters, digits, and underscores).

Answer (score 7):

http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html is a simple regex analyzer (among many others). <strike>Since its not linkable</strike>, here is <strike>just</strike> a screenshot and the [link](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html?regex=facebox%5C%5B%3F%5C.%28%5Cw+%29%5C%5D%3F&env=env_js):

[image]

Comment: There is actually a link at the bottom to "send to a friend": http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html?regex=facebox%5C%5B%3F%5C.%28%5Cw+%29%5C%5D%3F&env=env_java . Looks like a great tool though it is strange the way it sometimes cuts up bits of text.

Comment: @Chris, thanks, that's me and my attention span, and my expectation to see a "Link to this" somewhere in large font at the top of the site.

Comment: @miku: I'd given you the benefit of the doubt and assumed it was just a new feature since you first start using the site so you hadn't noticed it. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**I believe you are looking for is the** [**split()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) **function:**

What you mentioned about turning words into an array is typically referred to as a [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), so if you wanted to get "`otherword`" from "`facebox otherword`", you would do the following:

```
var test = "facebox otherword"
var word = test.split(' ')[1];
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqWn2/)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I get it now, really helpfull! I think I am going to use split in this case!

Answer (score 2):

Note `\.`. That means that it is a dot, rather than any character. This regex cathches `facebox.otherword`

Answer (score 1):

This matches text like:

```
facebox[.blabla]
facebox.blabla
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you have there won't match "facebook otherword", because of the `\.`. It's looking for a literal ".", so it would match the following: "facebook.otherword", "facebook[.otherword", "facebook.otherword]", or "facebook[.otherword]".

Answer (score 0):

Checks that the string contained in the `rel` property of `this`

1. contains the text 'facebox'
2. followed by 0 or 1 open-square-brackets
3. followed by a dot
4. followed by 1 or more word characters
5. followed by 0 or 1 close-square-brackets

If matched, the 1 or more word characters will be contained in a sub-match.

Answer (score 0):

`/facebox\[?\.(\w+)\]?/`

- matches `facebox` literal
- then optionally match `[`
- then match `.`
- then match any word
- then optionally match `]`